# A question involving a system of pulleys

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

**The problem**

I recently was trying to solve a problem (1) from David Morin's 'Classical Mechanics'(2). Before going ahead and solving the full problem, I tried solving a simpler version of it:

*In the diagram given below we have a system of pulleys and blocks. The pulleys and strings have negligible mass and the system is frictionless. All the blocks are of equal mass $m$. Find the acceleration of all the blocks.*

[image]

**The Solution according to the Book**

The reasoning of the book applied to this problem is as follows:

The tension throughout the string is a constant $T$ as the string is massless and there is no friction force involved. Therefore the accelerations $a$ and $a'$ in blocks $a$ & $d$ and $b$ & $c$ respectively is given by:

$$T-mg=ma$$

$$2T-mg=ma'$$

(Deriving the second equation used the fact that the pulleys are massless. Also the accelerations of the block are the accelerations along the upward direction.)

Since the length of string is constant:

$$\frac {d^2} {dt^2} (\sum \text {string pieces})=2a+4a'=0$$

Now the accelerations can be solved using the $3$ simultaneous equations.

**My Questions**

Note that according to the solution, strings $iii$ and $iv$ both move in the upward direction with the same acceleration. Doesn't this imply that the region of the string that is wrapped around the pulley $3$ should somehow get compressed? This behavior contradicts our assumption that the total length of the string does not change with time. What am I missing?

**Note**

1. Feel free to use Math in your answer. Also be as rigorous as possible.
2. If there is ambiguity or some silly error in this post, please mention.

**References**

- (1) To be precise the problem is problem $6$ 'Line of Pulleys' from chapter $2$.
- (2) Pdf versions of this book are available as well.

Comment: What part of the solution implies that strings *iii* and *iv* are moving upwards?  Maybe I'm missing something here, but all I see is statements about the motions of the pulleys.

Comment: You are correct! It was due to my misunderstanding of the equations and also due to my preconceived notions about how the ropes were moving which led to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note that according to the solution, strings $iii$ and $iv$ both move in the upward direction with the same acceleration.*
You are finding the accelerations of the pulleys/masses **not** portions of string, and the central pulley and the part of the string in contact with it does not move at all.
By moving upwards pulleys $2$ and $4$ shorten the length of sting, $(iii$ and $iv)$, between pulleys $2$ and $4$ and pulley $3$,

Answer (score 1):

[image]

from the FBD

The unknows are 8 tensions $~T_i~$ and 4
accelerations $~a_i~$ . Thus we need 12 equations

I ) Newton Equations

$$m_{{a}}a_{{1}}=T_{{1}}-m_{{a}}g\\
m_{{b}}a_{{2}}=T_{{7}}-m_{{b}}g\\
m_{{c}}a_{{3}}=T_{{8}}-m_{{c}}g\\
m_{{d}}a_{{4}}=T_{{6}}-m_{{d}}g$$

II) Newton Equations Massless Pulleys

$$-T_{{7}}+T_{{2}}+T_{{3}}=0\\
-T_{{8}}+T_{{4}}+T_{{5}}=0$$

III) Rope Equations

$$-T_{{1}}+T_{{2}}=0\\
-T_{{2}}+T_{{3}}=0\\
T_{{4}}+T_{{5}}=0\\
-T_{{5}}+T_{{6}}=0$$

IV) Kinematic Equations

$$a_{{1}}+a_{{4}}=0\\
a_{{2}}-a_{{3}}=0$$

The solution e.g.

$$a_1=-{\frac {g \left( -m_{{b}}m_{{d}}+m_{{c}}m_{{a}} \right) }{m_{{b}}m_{{
d}}+m_{{c}}m_{{a}}}}
\\
T_1=\,{\frac {m_{{a}}gm_{{b}}m_{{d}}}{m_{{b}}m_{{d}}+m_{{c}}m_{{a}}}}$$